# Created POST route, but resulting in RoutingError (No Route matches POST)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am setting up a new route "/v1/example_two" that I can POST to (create), however it is resulting in No route matches [POST] `RoutingError`

I have tried explicitly stating post, try to create the route through resources

**config/routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :roles, only: [:index], defaults: { format: :xml }

  defaults format: :json do
    scope :v1 do
      resources :example_one, only: [:create, :show], param: :uuid
      resources :example_two, only: [:create], param: :uuid
    end
  end
end
```

and I have a controller:

**app/controllers/example_two.rb**

```
class example_two < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
  end
end
```

I expect it to return whatever is in example_two#create, however it is resulting in `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] \"/v1/example_two\"` when I submit a POST request to `/v1/example_two` or `/v1/example_two/123` in Postman

Comment: Where is the `api` in your path specified, don't see it in the routes.rb file

Comment: what is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: @Eyeslandic Sorry, I meant I am making a POST request to `/v1/example_two` and `/v1/example_two/123` (not sure which one I should be posting to) using Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was modifying from the host machine instead of within the docker container, so `routes.rb` was not being updated